# Can you justify the existence of a $x_{*}$ solving $\mbox{li}(x_{*})=\mbox{erf}(x_{*})?$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, special-functions

Can you justify the existence of a $x_{*}$ solving 
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\li}{li}\DeclareMathOperator{\erf}{erf}\li(x_{*})=\erf(x_{*})?$$

Here $\li(x)$ is a special function, the so called [logarithmic integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicIntegral.html), I believe that the formula that you need for $\li(x)$ then is 
$$\li(x)=\int_\mu^x\frac{dt}{\log t}$$
where $\mu$ as you've read is *Soldner's constant*, and $$\erf(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$$ is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

I would like to see a numerical method computing a good approximation of such $x_*$, since my purpose is learn and refresh mathematicas, I would like to know/rememer what method works to get an approximation of such problem. *I don't need a good approximation* since I've used an online tool to compute this as $1.9653631831359533312687921...$, *but I would like to know an explanation of such method to compute* a good approximation for solve an integral equation (I don't take the derivative since I don't know how handle the derivative of $\li(x)$, wich is defined as a P.V.).

> **Question.** Can you justify the existence of a $x_{*}$ solving 
>   $$\li(x_{*})=\erf(x_{*}),$$
>   and give a explanation of a numerical method to compute this?

Comment: $\li(\mu)=0<\erf(\mu)$ and $\li\to \infty$ while $\erf\to 1$ so the solution must exist. Derivative is $\li'(x)=\frac 1{\log x}$.

Comment: Very thanks much @A.S. also for your notes, the [graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+li(x)%3Derf(x)) show it, but the graph that I did in my paper was confuse to me.

Comment: A Cauchy principal value often just differentiates in the same way as a normal integral; you can go back to the original definition of it to see this. Actually, since in your definition, the lower limit is the Soldner-Ramanujan constant, it is not even a PV integral anymore.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying it, also to *A.S.*, I'll wait an answer to my question, but I much appreciate your early remarks @J.M.  I would like learn it.

Comment: You know that you can just use Newton-Raphson for this, right?

Comment: @J.M. wouldn't you need to evaluate integrals repeatedly. to use Newtons?

Comment: @A.S., if that is the method you choose to evaluate the error function and the logarithmic integral, then yes. Otherwise, there are more efficient methods than quadrature that can be used.

Comment: Thanks I would like remember these methods, I learned these methods in a recent past, but I want to see how work with these now with right computations from the hand of an user that know how solve it @J.M.

Comment: Thanks I would like remember these methods, I learned these methods in a recent past, but I want to see how work with these now with right computations from the hand of an user that know how solve it @A.S. on the other had your proof for the existence is right. I didn't think solve as you said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider the function $$f(x)=\text{li}(x)-\text{erf}(x)$$ one easy way to find its zero is [Newton method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method). Starting from a reasonable guess $x_0$, it will be updated accoreding to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{\text{li}(x_n)-\text{erf}(x_n)}{\frac{1}{\log (x_n)}-\frac{2 e^{-x_n^2}}{\sqrt{\pi
   }}}$$ Starting using $x_0=2$, Newton method will then generate the following iterates $$x_1=1.9649503996039002033$$ $$x_2=1.9653631233745275939$$ $$x_3=1.9653631831359520789$$ $$x_4=1.9653631831359533313$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

You could have a faster convergence using [Halley method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley's_method) (it requires $f''(x)$). Starting again from $x_0=2$, the iterates will be $$x_1=1.9653642096145336397$$ $$x_2=1.9653631831359533313$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

You could even have a faster convergence using higher order methods (Newton is quadratic, Halley is cubic). Let me give you below the **first** iterate $x_1^{(n)}$ for this methods 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_1^{(n)} \\
 2 & 1.9649503996039002033 \\
 3 & 1.9653642096145336397 \\
 4 & 1.9653631809125822565 \\
 5 & 1.9653631829431668086 \\
 6 & 1.9653631831480595920 \\
 7 & 1.9653631831361504849 \\
 8 & 1.9653631831359467245 \\
 9 & 1.9653631831359532274
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Very thanks much, now I am starting to read it.

Comment: Very thanks much, I believe that your answer and the remarks of ***A.S.**, and **J.M.** give me the best answer, and I can remember in details how work this numerical methods. too thans to **kamil09875** for the edit.  Very thanks much.

Comment: @user243301. You are very welcome !